# HOC with hook for class component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am trying to write a HOC that uses hooks and passes values to class component props. This HOC should work with extended and non extended components.

```
// withHook.js

const withHook = (WrappedComponent) => {
  class WithProps extends React.Component {
    render() {
      return <WrappedComponent {...this.props} />;
    }
  }

  function WithHookProps(props) {
    const newProps = useMyHook(props);

    return <WithProps {...props} newProps={newProps} />;
  }

  return WithHookProps;
};

export default withHook;
```

usage:

```
// ComponentA.js
class ComponentA extends React.Component {
 get newProps() {
   return this.props.newProps;
 }
 render() {
   ...
 }
}
export default withHook(ComponentA);
```

This works as expected. BUT! It doesn't work with extended components.
Example:

```
// ComponentB.js
class ComponentB extends React.Component {
 ...
}
export default withHook(ComponentB);
```

```
// ComponentC.js
class ComponentC extends ComponentB {
 ...
}
```

Now I get an error: TypeError: Cannot call a class as a function at _classCallCheck (classCallCheck.js:3:1).

I assume that's because HOC returns function, not class component. What should I do?

Comment: You are correct, `withHook` returns a _function_, which can't be extended as a class. [Component inheritance is _not_ recommended](https://legacy.reactjs.org/docs/composition-vs-inheritance.html) for a variety of reasons (one of which you are seeing above). You should be _composing_ your components not having them inherit from other components.

Comment: That's not possible now, I can't rewrite the whole project. I need a solution, even if it's not recommended.